# Handling Call Waiting while in Offhook State

Tags: android, phone-state-listener

I am making an app to monitor calls. The app works properly when I call or get a call (Outgoing and incoming) by identifying the current state and the previous state in PhoneStateListener.

For example when previous state is `TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE` and the new state is `TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK`, then it's an outgoing call.

And if Previous state was `TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING` and the new state is `TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK`, it's an incoming call.

If the previous state was `TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING` and the new state is `TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE`, then it's definitely a Missed call.

Now the problem comes when I needed to handle call waiting too in it. I have two scenario here. The first one is when the user doesn't pick the call and the waited call becomes a missed call. Another scenario would be when the user picks the new call by putting the current call on hold, hangs the new call and picks the held call. THe problem is I get same states in both the scenario, even the call numbers are same. Here's the change of state as they happen -

```
(Numbers have been changed for privacy reasons)
OFFHOOK. Number = 123456 //Dials an outgoing call
RINGING. Number = 654321 //Gets a new call while on call
OFFHOOK. Number = 654321 //Rejects the new incoming call. Why it shows the new incoming number while the call is offhook with the outgoing call.
IDLE. Number = 123456 //Ends the outgoing call

OFFHOOK. Number = 123456 //Dials an outgoing call
RINGING. Number = 654321 //Gets a new call while on call
OFFHOOK. Number = 654321 //Accepts the new incoming call
//Hanging the incoming call has no events surprisingly
IDLE. Number = 123456 //Ends the outgoing call
```

SO my question is, is there any way to identify these two scenario while still on call. I know there's one way to do it by checking the call logs after the call is finished, but I need to do it while being on call.

Comment: You found any solution for this?

Comment: @AH. Not yet! Still looking for the solution.

Comment: I am so experience the same problem.Somebody please suggest a solution